# Is the initial sound in the word RHS a vowel sound?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

In order to specify whether *a* or *an*, I need to know whether the articulation is with [ar] like vowel sound or [r] like consonant sound. So is RHS a vowel or a consonant sounding in the initial? So *a RHS* or *an RHS*?

Comment: What is *RHS*? Is this an onomatopoeic exclamation? The initials of an organization?

Comment: acronyms aren't words per se. But if this represents a thing, I'd say "an RHS" because "a RHS" the "a" is going to get slurred into it.

Comment: @choster abbreviation for a technical system such as `a removal heat system (RHS)` :)

Comment: You will need to use an before RHS because of its pronunciation (Are-Eh-Ess). The best hint for this will be "an hour"

Comment: Related: [Pronouncing acronyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29374), [General rule for pronouncing initialisms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30608)

Comment: What! {Removal heat system} I presumed you were taking about the Royal Horticultural Society or even *right-hand side* (I'm pretty sure they'd use an *an*). On a different note, you should be careful using acronym to refer to RHS, if it were an acronym it would be pronounce *arse*, like NASA, while RHS is an initialism because you pronounce each letter independently.

Comment: All roads in similar questions lead back to the nominated duplicate. There are a large number of similar questions listed in the sidebar as well which may help.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Initially, I voted to close as a duplicate of that question, but I retracted it after a second look because they really are not the same. The answer there, "It depends on whether the abbreviation is an acronym or an initialism," is in fact an assumption of this question. hhh already knew that "In order to specify whether a or an, I need to know whether the articulation is with [ar] like vowel sound or [r] like consonant sound." The question here is really not about the rule for choosing "a" or "an"; it's about how to know how to pronounce "RHS."

Comment: @AndrewLeach: That's why I think "[Pronouncing acronyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29374)" is more relevant. If I were to close as duplicate, that's the target I'd pick.

Answer (score 0):

You should say ***an*** RHS because it is spoken out loud as [Are-Aitch-Ess] with initials. Sometimes, people say acronyms differently but apparently not here like FAG '[Ef Ei Ge]' (an FAG) or '[F \ae g]' (a FAG).

RHS could stand for Royal Horticultural Society and Removal Heat System.

*Related*

> 1. [Pronouncing acronyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29374/pronouncing-acronyms)
> 2. [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)
> 3. [General rule for pronouncing initialisms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30608/general-rule-for-pronouncing-initialisms)

Comment: *[Are-Eh-Ess]* sounds more like RAS surely it should be spelled *Aitch* (or *Haitch* as some insist)

Comment: @suməlic Changed.

Comment: Definitely *an*. *An RHS (Royal Horticultural Society) employee informed me that the best time for planting chrysanthemums is April or May*.