# How can I tell when an abbreviation is an acronym?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms, differences

I know an acronym is an abbreviation that can be pronounced as one word, but when is an abbreviation pronounced as one word?

Making myself clearer, how do we know whether or not it is pronounced as one word or not? Is there any definite rule to go by? For example, today, we were discussing "**AYAD**", whether or not this was an abbreviation or acronym. We didn't know, and we didn't know how to tell whether or not it was an acronym.

So,:

1. Is there a rule to go by to determine an acronym from an abbreviation?
2. If there is, what is it?

Can someone please provide some details on this? Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pronouncing acronyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29374/pronouncing-acronyms/29386#29386)

Comment: I believe technically what you are asking for is the difference between an acronym and an initialism: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3755/8019

Comment: @Philoto, I already know what an acronym is. My question is, how can you tell it *is* an acronym, if you didn't know how to pronounce it. How could you tell it was pronounced as a single word only?

Comment: That question is answered in the link I posted earlier. You simply can't.

Comment: _I don't_ know what an acronym is. I've seen three conflicting definitions. More, if one uses 'initial components' rather than 'initial letters' in the definition. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) says there is no consensus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is, you can't.  If you are having a conversation with someone who uses an acronym, the only way you'd know is if they spelled out the letters.  Otherwise, you'd simply have to ask.  And obviously used in written form such as an e-mail, you'd never know if it were an acronym outside of context.  Though a good list can be found [here](http://www.muller-godschalk.com/acronyms.html).

A good rule of thumb is that acronyms that might look difficult to sound out are likely spelled instead (FBI, FDA, IBM to name a few).

Comment: Could you make your answer official, by referencing perhaps? I'd like a good solid argument, not just stating "you can't". Pardon my fussiness, but I just want to make *absolutely* sure.

Comment: GNU's Not Unix ;)

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: You're asking for a reference for the *absence* of a rule?

Comment: +1: I think the only rule is to try and sound it out as an acronym, and if it doesn't "flow" then spell it out as an initialism instead.

Comment: @Colin the first rule of EL&U is that you don't talk about EL&U !

Comment: Sorry, Ham and Bacon, but Neil's correct: There's no way to know - you can't tell just by looking. However, some are easier than others to deduce. "FBI" and "IBM," for example. The more the construction looks pronounceable, the more likely it is: "NASA," "FEMA." But: "DOT." They're all case-by-case.

Comment: I found only one page explaining the absence of a rule for acronyms [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31864/how-can-i-tell-when-an-abbreviation-is-an-acronym/31870).