# Can an acronym be pronounced as a construction of letters and words?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

I've found this question [Pronouncing acronyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29374/pronouncing-acronyms) in which people discuss how to pronounce acronyms, and they can be pronounced either as single letters or as a single word.

However I would like to know if they can be pronounced as a combination. For example in computer science SPOF stands for Single Point Of Failure, can it be pronounced as S.POF? Or it must be pronounced either as 'spof' or S.P.O.F.?

Answer (score 1):

It could be pronounced /ˈesˌpɒf/ , particularly if it's to be put against Multiple Points of Failure, which could only be pronounced/ˈemˌpɒf/.

However, wordifying acronyms will generally result in as few syllables as possible, so pronouncing SPOF as /spɒf/ is what would normally be expected.

Comment: I think this would like *spuff*.

Comment: Would you rather have /spɑ:f/? I thought that a short o was written ɒ and the pronunciation varied between AmE and BrE.

Comment: Sure, sure, sure. I was just trying to think of a joke about *spiffs* whose answer could be *spuff*. :)

Comment: Ah. I suppose something which might currently be *spiffing* could have *spuff* last week.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends if the letters of the acronym (depending on the first letters of the organisations or other item's name spell a reasonable word in the first place) are reasonable enough or not. 
As an example in my area of working in libraries, the Dewey Decimal Classification is called 'Dee Dee Cee' when using the acronym, but the Australian Library/Information Association' spells ALIA which is pronounced as Ar-lee-ar.'
Many places intentionally 'make' their acronyms spell a word for this very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A complication here is some confusion over how you define *acronym*. Some say that it is any string of initial letters and a synonym of *initialism*. Others say that an *acronym* is a word made of initial letters (like Nato) and it is an *initialism* if you pronounce each letter separately as in HTML.

This is not universal though:

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acronym)

Definition of acronym

*an abbreviation formed from the initial letters of other words and pronounced as a word (e.g. ASCII, NASA). Compare with initialism.*

and:

Definition of initialism

*an abbreviation consisting of initial letters pronounced separately (e.g. BBC). Compare with acronym.*

While this seems clear enough, compare with Dictionary.com:

ac·ro·nym

1.
*a word formed from the initial letters or groups of letters of words in a set phrase or series of words, as Wac  from Women's Army Corps, OPEC  from Organization of Petroleum Exporting Countries,  or loran  from long-range navigation.*

but...

in·i·tial·ism
1.
*a name or term formed from the initial letters of a group of words and pronounced as a separate word, as NATO  for North Atlantic Treaty organization;  an acronym.*

2.
*a set of initials representing a name, organization, or the like, with each letter pronounced separately, as FBI  for Federal Bureau of Investigation.*

Contrast this with OED:

acronym, n.

1. *A group of initial letters used as an abbreviation for a name or expression, each letter or part being pronounced separately; an initialism (such as ATM, TLS).*
2. *A word formed from the initial letters of other words or (occas.) from the initial parts of syllables taken from other words, the whole being pronounced as a single word (such as NATO, RADA).*

So, OED's *acronym* is the same as Dictionary.com's *initialism*. For *initialism* OED says:

*The use of initials; a significative group of initial letters. Now spec. a group of initial letters used as an abbreviation for a name or expression, each letter or part being pronounced separately (contrasted with acronym n.).*

Summary: ODO says that an acronym is a word and an initialism is letters. Dictionary.com says that an acronym is a word but an initialism can be a word or letters. OED says that an acronym is a word or letters, but an initialism can be only letters.

Comment: I've also come across a stricter definition, restricting the acronym class to the few strings that are now rendered virtually universally as genuine words of lower-case letters. Thus _radar_ and _scuba_ would be acronyms, _NATO_ and _ISA_ hemi-acronyms (my term) and _BBC_ and _ATM_ initialisms. I think this was in a Bloomsbury publication. _The US of A_ would be under the abbreviations umbrella.