# Is an "acronoun" a real concept?

Tags: meaning, nouns, acronyms

In discussing pronunciation of difference kinds of acronyms and initialisms, I recalled the term "acronoun."  However, I can't find any reference to this term on the Wikipedia [Acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) page, nor in google searching.  I am questioning where I would have heard this before and if it is a real concept.

If I had to guess at a definition, it would be an acronym that is pronounced as a word and used like a noun.  However, that might be true for most acronyms or there might be a different word for this.

I am looking for any insight or evidence this either is our could be a concept.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a malaprop for acronym. Someone out there may have tried to coin a neologism, but it's not like it's caught on. Why not ask for an Acroverb or an Acrojective?

Comment: Most commonly found on Google: Spanish-language sites with the three words "a crono un" in succession.

Comment: Not sure if this is technically a dupe (someone more familiar with ELU can probably decide), but the accepted answer here does answer your question, I think: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29374/pronouncing-acronyms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't exist in OED. That's as close as you can get to a certain answer that it's not a word.